# android.widget.ImageButton cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming and I'm trying to write a simple game.

The problem is I came not that far and I'm encountering my first problem I try to search for a solution on the internet but with no success.

Error message:

> `android.widget.ImageButton` cannot be cast to
>   `android.widget.RelativeLayout`

**The error appears on this line of code:**

```
Btn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
```

I'm using `Eclipse` and also try to clean the project but with no success either.

Java file:

```
package com.example.tapthevac;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout Btn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Btn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);

    Btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }

    });

    Btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }

    });

}

}
```

XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/re/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/space"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tapthevac.MainActivity" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:src="@drawable/start" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what you exactly wants to do ...??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your xml file - `imagebutton1` is an id of an ImageButton not of a RelativeLayout, so change the type of `Btn` to ImageButton and write the following lines:

```
ImageButton Btn;
....
Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
```

The other parts of the code are okay.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
Btn = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
```

Change it to:

```
Btn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
```

You are trying to convert ImageView to RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

- You should cast as ImageButton as your view is a ImageView button

Btn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);

Answer (score 0):

**Use:**

```
ImageView btn;

btn = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.your_image_button);
```

Make sure you understand how basic casting works in java.